# Corona sdk, get the rect of a sprite to generate his physics body

Tags: graphics, lua, box2d, coronasdk, game-physics

I have a sprite like this, instanced inside a class, that includes a file generated with [texture packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker), with all the sprites:

```
local sheetInfo = require("db.sprites." .. self.element["name"])
self.sheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "db/sprites/" .. self.element["name"] .. ".png", sheetInfo:getSheet() )
self.sprite = display.newSprite( self.sheet , element["animations"] )
self.sprite.xScale, self.sprite.yScale = 0.3, 0.3
```

Now, my goal is to generate dynamically a physic rectangle that fits the sprite. In the normal case, it's quite simple. My code is:

```
function defineBody(sprite)
    if (sprite.xScale == 1 and sprite.yScale == 1) then return nil end
    local shape = {}
    local wx, wy = sprite.width * sprite.xScale/2, sprite.height * sprite.yScale/2
    local nwx, nwy = sprite.width * sprite.xScale/-2, sprite.height * sprite.yScale/-2
    shape[1],shape[2] = nwx, nwy
    shape[3],shape[4] = wx, nwy
    shape[5],shape[6] = wx, wy
    shape[7],shape[8] = nwx, wy
    return shape
end
```

Then I call this function like this:

```
physics.addBody( self.sprite, self.element["physics"], { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3, shape=defineBody(sprite)} )
```

Result:
[image: result]

My question is:

How to change that function to work well when the anchor point of the image also changes? Example:

```
self.sprite.anchorX, self.sprite.anchorY = 0.5, 1
```

I tried a lot, but I didn't found a simple way to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever checked out physics editor? You can create phyics objects inside of other physics objects like you are describing you would like to do.

http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

I know this is an old video, but this helped me a ton when I was first starting out with Corona:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DL_or4XKTfU

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know physics editor, but I was searching a way to build programmatically a "default body" for the sprites, so I don't have to manually define it for each sprite... but... +1 for answering me :P